# installing ubuntu on a partition with data

Tags: partitioning

I have two hard drives in my computer, one with just data and no OS, three partitions, the other with windows 8 also with three partitions. Now i want to install Ubuntu on the Hard drive with no OS, on the first partition with 30 gigs free, total 100 gigs. I want to know, should i move my data from the first partition and format it, or just install without making any changes? Rather than that, i would like your suggestions on installation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to install it? Using wubi installer or booting from a cd / usb ?

If you plan to use wubi, installing on the first partition should be fine. But if you want to install from a stick or usb, I recommend to create a new partition or to free one of them.

Comment: I do not want use wubi installer or dual booting, i want to keep my windows 8 OS and Ubuntu on separate hard drives, no dual boot! change my booting preference from the BIOS.

Comment: Then you should move your data from the first drive or as I said above, maybe create a new partition.

I had problems changing the booting preference too with windows 8 :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend resizing that partition in the primary OS and then installing ubuntu onto that empty partition. Rezising differs depending on the primary OS.